# NavLink activeClassName selected on page load

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

Is it possible to push with history.push the url of the route on useEffect to maintain selected a Navlink on page load?

*Navigation.tsx*

```
export const Navigation = ({ userId }: { userId: Id }) => {
  const [ownEvents, setOwnEvents] = useState<EventsPerMonth[]>();
  const [attendedEvents, setAttendedEvents] = useState<EventsPerMonth[]>();
  const { url, path } = useRouteMatch();
  const { push } = useHistory()

  useEffect(() => {
    getCreatedEventsByUserId(userId).then(setOwnEvents);
    getAssistedEventsByUserId(userId).then(setAttendedEvents);
    push(`${url}/created-events`);
  }, [userId, push, url]);

  return (
    <>
      <StyledNavigation>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <StyledNavLink to={`${url}/created-events`} activeClassName="any">
              Eventos creados
            </StyledNavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <StyledNavLink to={`${url}/assisted-events`} activeClassName="any">
              Eventos asistidos
            </StyledNavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </StyledNavigation>

      <Switch>
        <ProtectedRoute exact path={`${path}/created-events`}>
          {attendedEvents && <EventsList events={attendedEvents} />}
        </ProtectedRoute>
        <ProtectedRoute exact path={`${path}/assisted-events`}>
          {ownEvents && <EventsList events={ownEvents} />}
        </ProtectedRoute>
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};
```

Is allowed?

```
useEffect(() => {
    getCreatedEventsByUserId(userId).then(setOwnEvents);
    getAssistedEventsByUserId(userId).then(setAttendedEvents);
    push(`${url}/created-events`);
  }, [userId, push, url]);
```

Is there any other way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you just asking if you can issue a navigation action as a side-effect in the `useEffect` hook? If so, yes, that is allowed. Anything else? Is this not working as expected?

Comment: I'm asking if is allowed to do a history.push on useEffect, but I'm also asking if there is another clean way to do that. Thanks!

Comment: There are certainly other ways to handle/effect this navigation. Does this `Navigation` component need to *really* be rendered the `".../created-events"` path? Can the UI just render `Navigate` on the the correct path from the start? Or is is that you want `Navigate` to redirect to the `".../created-events"` route that it is rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issuing the navigation action from the `useEffect` hook is completely valid and allowed. Though, since it seems this `Navigation` component is really just calling some APIs to populate some local state and unconditionally navigating to one of the children routes, I'd probably suggest using a redirect (REPLACE) instead of a navigation (PUSH) action to help cut down on entries on the history stack.

```
const { replace } = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
  getCreatedEventsByUserId(userId).then(setOwnEvents);
  getAssistedEventsByUserId(userId).then(setAttendedEvents);
  replace(`${url}/created-events`);
}, [userId, history, url]);
```

In fact, this redirect seems to only serve to get the user to the sub-route. You could render a `Redirect` instead, to redirect from the `path` to `"{path}/created-events"`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getCreatedEventsByUserId(userId).then(setOwnEvents);
  getAssistedEventsByUserId(userId).then(setAttendedEvents);
}, [userId, history, url]);

...

<Switch>
  <ProtectedRoute exact path={`${path}/created-events`}>
    {attendedEvents && <EventsList events={attendedEvents} />}
  </ProtectedRoute>
  <ProtectedRoute exact path={`${path}/assisted-events`}>
    {ownEvents && <EventsList events={ownEvents} />}
  </ProtectedRoute>
  <Redirect to={`${path}/created-events`} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Incredible @Drew Reese! Your solution solved another problem I had when opening the profile with the created events clicked. When I went back with the mouse, it went to the profile WITHOUT the clicked events even though the previous page was not the profile and the feeling was strange... Thanks for your time and your knowledge